# How to find the range of a step for a random number

Tags: python, random, range

I've just started learning code and i'm writing a simple program.
I'm trying to figure out how to find the range of a step that a number is within.For example i have a range of 0 to 101 with a step of 10.
Let's say the number is 33, so the range of a step it's in goes from 30 to 40.

How can i find these lower and upper values or what can i use for it ?

I have a solution for this but it is very messy and i want to find a better way of doing it so that i don't have to repeat the code.Here it is

```py
import random
number = random.randint(1, 100)
def help():
    if number in range(0, 11):
        print ("It's between 0 and 10")
    if number in range(10, 21):
        print ("It's between 10 and 20")
    if number in range(20, 31):
        print ("It's between 20 and 30")
    if number in range(30, 41):
        print ("It's between 30 and 40")
    if number in range(40, 51):
        print ("It's between 40 and 50")
    if number in range(50, 61):
        print ("It's between 50 and 60")
    if number in range(60, 71):
        print ("It's between 60 and 70")
    if number in range(70, 81):
        print ("It's between 70 and 80")
    if number in range(80, 91):
        print ("It's between 80 and 90")
    if number in range(90, 101):
        print ("It's between 90 and 100")
print (number)
help()
```

So i basically need to automate this code so that i would only have to pass on values to get the same output.

Comment: `start = (number // 10) * 10`

Comment: It's good that you picked up on one of the very core things you should learn when programming. "i want to find a better way of doing it so that i don't have to repeat the code" - This is key, if you ever copy paste code, there's most likely a better way. In this case, consider the numerical properties of the ranges. You can express or calculate start and ends in terms of division much easier than writing out all ranges yourself.

Comment: If you want your ranges to all have the same size, you should make the combined range be 0 through 99.  That way you can have 10 ranges of 10 values each.  In your example, your ranges overlap and are not all the same size.

Comment: jonrsharpe thank you 
TomKarzes thanks for clearing that up because i actually thought that they were the same size

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import random
number = random.randint(1, 100)
def help():
    n=0
    while True:
        if number<n:
            print("It's between ",n-10,n)
            break
        n+=10
print (number)
help()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use print like this :

```
print ("It's between "+str(number//10*10) +" and "+str((number//10+1)*10))
```

Comment: You should code-highlight the code portion of your answer.  It would also be cleaner if you avoided repeat calculations by using a variable.